# Сериализация std::string

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, сериализация

Собственно, есть класс:

```
class MyClass{
   const uint64_t UUID;
   const std::string Version;
   const uint32_t blocksize;
}
```

Как его записать в файл?

Comment: Записать **КАК**? Как текстовый, как бинарный?

Comment: Встречные вопросы:
1) Вам нужен бинарный или текстовый формат?
2) А строка у вас может быть только в одной кодировке?

Comment: @gbg бинарный, строка в одной кодировке

Comment: @Harry как бинарный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, я бы делал примерно так... Я переделал в `struct`, чтобы не возиться с доступом, и убрал `const` с полей - потому как записать константные поля легко, а вот читать - нет: не следует менять константный объект. Разве что если чтение выполняется в конструкторе, как инициализация...

```
struct MyClass
{

    MyClass (uint64_t uuid, const char * s, uint32_t b):UUID(uuid),
             Version(s),blocksize(b){}

    uint64_t UUID;
    std::string Version;
    uint32_t blocksize;

    ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
    istream& read(istream& is);
};

ostream& MyClass::write(ostream& os) const
{
    os.write((char*)&UUID,sizeof(UUID));
    size_t s = Version.size();
    os.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
    os.write(Version.c_str(),s);
    os.write((char*)&blocksize,sizeof(blocksize));
    return os;
}

istream& MyClass::read(istream& is)
{
    is.read((char*)&UUID,sizeof(UUID));
    size_t s;
    is.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
    Version.resize(s);
    is.read(Version.data(),s);
    is.read((char*)&blocksize,sizeof(blocksize));
    return is;
}
```

Ну, и как пример использования:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a(1,"xyz",3);
    MyClass b(4,"s",8);

    ofstream out("data",ios::binary);
    a.write(out);
    out.close();

    ifstream in("data",ios::binary);
    b.read(in);
    in.close();

    cout << b.UUID << endl;
    cout << b.Version << endl;
    cout << b.blocksize << endl;
}
```

Сами проверьте, что все работает.

Как вариант для компиляторов, не желающих работать с `.data()` -

```
Version.resize(s);
is.read(Version.data(),s);
```

заменить на

```
char * buf = new char[s];
is.read(buf,s);
Version.assign(buf,buf+s);
delete[] buf;
```

Comment: is.read(Version.data(),s); выдает ошибку

Comment: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::char_type *' (aka 'char *') with an rvalue of type 'const char *'

Comment: Нужен [компилятор поновее](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). Дописал еще один вариант.

Comment: Забавно, одного минусатора я знаю, с пимиентскими блинчи... main'ами то есть :) А второму-то что не нравится?

Comment: Не знаю, я поставил плюс

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо (хз, почему-то коммент-спасибка удаляется постоянно)

Comment: Если длина строки с версией не бесконечна, то гораздо более безопасным будет  зафиксировать версию как массив символов, и добавить поле с длиной этих данных дабы не словить внезапно сегментейшн фаулт, только потому, что файл поврежден или нолик затерся в процессе переделок с версии на версию. лучше манипулировать примитивными типами данных. `is.read(buf,s)` может завершиться раньше чем будет прочтено s-символов, а вы смело их добавите к строке без проверки is.gcount(). что чревато крашем в неожиданный момент и долгой отладкой потом.